# Child component rendered even its parent did not

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about rendering in React. See the image below

[image]

The `SelectableGroup` component is rendered because it changes its state (calling `setState()`). Then all its children are rendered until `DashboardConfigs` component. The `DashboardConfigs` component is not rendered because its `shouldComponentUpdate()` returns false.

Now my question is, why `Grid` and all other descendants of the `DashboardConfigs` are rendered?

I thought returning false from `shouldComponentUpdate` should cut off the whole branch of components tree from rendering process.

Note that:

- I use react-redux, but the `Grid` is not connected to the store.
- The `SelectableGroup` and `Grid` are components from react-bootstrap library. They probably use a context for its internal purposes. Could be a context the reason for redrawing? (I don't know how context works yet)

Comment: It could so happen that context property changed and the component Grid was using one of the changed context property causing it to rerender

Answer (score 2):

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

"...
Note that returning false does not prevent child components from re-rendering when their state changes."

I don't know how component is written, but you should make sure the child component's state does not change

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but looking at the Grid component in developer tools - it has not any state. Only props.

Comment: you can use [react profiler](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html) to check why the component render

Comment: The image from question is from react profiler. There is nothing about why the Grid component is rendered